# How to allow specific user access to firebase nodes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I want to allow all logged in user access to create new content, but only those who are owners should be able to update the data. I can't figure out how to do this, this is what I have tried:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "videos": {
      ".read": true,
      ".indexOn": ["id", "title_lower_case"],
      "$video": {
        ".write": "(auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password' && (!newData.exists() || newData.hasChildren())) || (auth.uid === root.child('videos').child($video).child('uid').val())",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['id', 'title', 'title_lower_case', 'uid'])",
        "id": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length >= 5 && newData.val().length <= 1000"
        },
        "title": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length >= 2 && newData.val().length <= 1000"
        },
        "title_lower_case": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length >= 2 && newData.val().length <= 1000"
        },
        "uid": {
          ".validate": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": false
        }
      }
    },
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      "$user": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $user && (!newData.exists() || newData.hasChildren())",
        ".indexOn": "name_lower_case",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['email', 'name', 'name_lower_case'])",
        "email": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length <= 2000"
        },
        "name": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length >= 2 && newData.val().length <= 2000"
        },
        "name_lower_case": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length >= 2 && newData.val().length <= 2000"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".validate": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I thought that this part allowed any logged in user to create a new node:

```
auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password' && (!newData.exists() || newData.hasChildren())
```

And this part only allowed owners to edit the node:

```
auth.uid === root.child('videos').child($video).child('uid').val()
```

Btw, I use the simple login feature in firebase if that has anything to say.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the below seemed to do the trick. If the auth variable exists, then allow write abilities. Due to me not fully understanding these rules, I have to wonder if this is running against the current user or if it's checking to see if any user is logged in.

```
{
    "rules": {
      "product":{
        ".read": true,
        ".write":"auth !== null"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this only checks if you are logged in, not if you are the owner of the "video", right?